# Android: heap error importing ShowcaseView as project, ClassNotFound if as JAR, Out of Memory

Tags: java, android, import, out-of-memory, showcaseview

I'm trying to get ShowcaseView into my Android project. I forked the repo from GitHub and tried to run the demo app, but couldn't because of a Java Heap error.

```
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

I tried to increase Eclipse and RunConfiguration memory heap but couldn't solve the issue. I also never had a java heap space error in months, so I wonder if there is some kind of loop somewhere generating a too large amount of RAM request.

Since importing the project didn't work, but building does work, I tried to import the ShowcaseView library JAR file directly in the libs folder of my project. My project ran but had a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.R$styleable
```

What can I do? Did anybody ever experience this kind of issue? I really love this library and would like to have this feature in my project, but I'm so stuck with this issue :-/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue, due to the Robolectric JAR included in the library. The issue is detailed on [Github](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/issues/108), and there also seems to be a workaround there too. I'll investigate further and update the library soon with a fix!

Comment: Sounds great. I'll try and use the workaround, and then look for your update :-) Thank you for the fast response!